# OnFocusChangeListener doesn't work in BaseAdapter?

Tags: android

I'm trying use `setOnFocusChangeListener` in my EditText with BaseAdapter. I want when EditText lost focus does set a value of a calculator but I can't understand why does always set zero in EditText after lost focus. I think the problem is with Android Version because version 4.3 works fine, but version 4.4.2 doesn't work.

How could I do it?

```
public class VendasProdutoListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context context;
    private List<Produto> lista;

    public VendasProdutoListAdapter(Context context, List<Produto> lista) {
        this.context = context;
        this.lista = lista;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return lista.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return lista.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }


    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final Produto produto = lista.get(position);
        final ItensVenda item = new ItensVenda();
        final ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.venda_produto_listadapter, parent, false);

            holder.llVendaProdutoListAdapter = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.llVendaProdutoListAdapter);
            holder.tvQtdEstoque = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvQtdEstoque);
            holder.tvNomeProduto = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvNomeProduto);
            holder.sivImagemProduto = (SmartImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.sivImagemProduto);
            holder.cbBrinde = (CheckBox)convertView.findViewById(R.id.cbBrinde);
            holder.cbEntregaFutura = (CheckBox)convertView.findViewById(R.id.cbEntregaFutura);
            holder.etQtd = (EditText)convertView.findViewById(R.id.etQtd);
            holder.btComprar = (Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.btComprar);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }else{
            holder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
        }

        holder.tvQtdEstoque.setText(String.valueOf(produto.getQuantidade()));
        holder.tvNomeProduto.setText(produto.getNome() + " R$ " + FormataMonetarios.getMoney(produto.getPreco_venda()));

        //checkbox
        holder.cbBrinde.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(holder.cbBrinde.isChecked()){
                    item.setBrinde(1);
                }else{
                    item.setBrinde(0);
                }
            }
        });
        holder.cbEntregaFutura.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(holder.cbEntregaFutura.isChecked()){
                    item.setEntregaFutura(1);
                }else{
                    item.setEntregaFutura(0);
                }
                Log.i("ENTREGA FUTURA->", item.getEntregaFutura() + "");
            }
        });
        //

        //edittext quantidade
        holder.etQtd.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                if(!hasFocus){
                    int qtd = Integer.parseInt(holder.etQtd.getText().toString());
                    if (qtd > produto.getQuantidade()){
                        Toast.makeText(context, "Nosso estoque não possuí esta quantidade", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        return convertView;
    }


    private static class ViewHolder{
        LinearLayout llVendaProdutoListAdapter;
        TextView tvQtdEstoque;
        SmartImageView sivImagemProduto;
        TextView tvNomeProduto;
        CheckBox cbBrinde;
        CheckBox cbEntregaFutura;
        EditText etQtd;
        Button btComprar;
    }
}
```